# Do while loops in Java not check their conditions if there is no body?

Tags: java, while-loop

In this example I have a simple JFrame containing a JButton with an ActionListener tied to it. This AcitonListener just changes a boolean flag that should allow the program to complete.

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        final boolean[] flag = new boolean[1];
        flag[0] = false;
        JFrame myFrame = new JFrame("Test");
        JButton myButton = new JButton("Click Me!");
        myButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                System.out.println("Button was clicked!");
                flag[0] = true;
            }
        });
        myFrame.add(myButton);
        myFrame.setSize(128,128);
        myFrame.setVisible(true);
        System.out.println("Waiting");
        while(!flag[0]){}
        System.out.println("Finished");
    }
}
```

This never prints "Finished", and after the button has been clicked once prints

```
Waiting
Button was clicked!
```

However, if I modify the while loop to read

```
while(!flag[0]){
    System.out.println("I should do nothing. I am just a print statement.");
}
```

This works! The printout looks like

```
Waiting
I should do nothing. I am just a print statement.
I should do nothing. I am just a print statement.
....
I should do nothing. I am just a print statement.
Button was clicked!
Finished
```

I understand this probably isn't the proper way to wait on an action, but nonetheless I am interested in knowing why Java behaves this way.

Comment: Have a look at this http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/

Answer (score 7):

The likeliest reason is that `flag[0] = true;` is executed on the UI thread, whereas `while(!flag[0])` is executed on the main thread.

Without synchronization, there is no guarantee that the change made in the UI thread will be visible from the main thread.

By adding the `System.out.println` you introduce a synchronization point (because the println method is `synchronized`) and the problem gets solved.

You could make `flag` a volatile instance or class boolean variable (not an array), or, more simply, put whatever code you want executed on the button being pressed in the listener itself.

---

For reference, the code with a volatile variable would look like this:

```
private static volatile boolean flag;
public static void main(String[] args) {
  JFrame myFrame = new JFrame("Test");
  JButton myButton = new JButton("Click Me!");
  myButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    @Override public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
      System.out.println("Button was clicked!");
      flag = true;
    }
  });
  myFrame.add(myButton);
  myFrame.setSize(128, 128);
  myFrame.setVisible(true);
  System.out.println("Waiting");
  while (!flag) { }
  System.out.println("Finished");
}
```

Comment: Also `while(!flag[0]){}` is extremely agressive on the CPU. I suppose OP is using Java 7 since he has to declare the Boolean final. With Java 8, he could use a `boolean volatile` directly.

Comment: @GuillaumeF. you can't declare a local volatile variable - it would have to be a field so doesn't need to be final in Java 7 or 8.

Comment: Oh you are right about the local volatile limitation. Thanks